# What is the name of a gene whose effect comes from the dominant and recessive alleles

Tags: genetics

The `p53` gene has a mutation which results in the cell having a cancerous phenotype.  This effect is dominant as one allele being mutated is enough to result in this effect.  However when both alleles are mutated then the phenotype changes / become more pronounced so it's not a simple dominant mutation.  What is this kind of mutation called?  Is it hemi-dominant or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Allelic effects**

> What is the name of a gene whose effect [..]

The concept of dominance make sense for alleles. The gene has no name to refer to the allelic interaction.

**Patterns of dominance**

Patterns of dominance and recessivity are typically used for quantitative traits. Can you somehow put a a number into the phenotypes of all three genotypes? Making some kind of association table would help even if the phenotypes are not quantitative. See below.

**Attempt to answer the question**

It looks like you are considering a case where the phenotypes

```
aa -> healthy
Aa -> sick
AA -> very sick
```

Under this model, it is hard to tell whether you would consider `sick` half way through `healthy` and `very sick` or not. It feels like you want to consider `sick` as being closer to `very sick` than to `healthy` so if we put numbers we could get something like

```
aa -> 1 (healthy)
Aa -> 2 (sick)
AA -> 2.5 (very sick)
```

As such, `A` shows [partial dominance (aka incomplete dominance or semi-dominance)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_(genetics)#Incomplete_dominance).